# issue and crash after deletion of last row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i am struggling from last 2 hours. Why last row is not deleting from my table view. A row is only remaining in table view which not removing. Although  i removed the object from array and nothing is in array.

What is problem in code ?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        Geofencing *getObject = [routesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [getObject deleteGeofencingFormDatabase:getObject.ah_routeid];

        [routesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            [routeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self displayEmptyRouteAlert];

        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
 -(void)displayEmptyRouteAlert
 {
  routesArray = [[Geofencing sharedInstance] fetchGeofencingFromDatabase];

if(routesArray.count > 0){
    [routeTableView reloadData];
}
else{

    NSString *messageStr = @"Let's start by creating new route.";
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No route found"
                                                                   message:messageStr
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction *buttonAdd = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add New Route" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self openToAddNewRoute];
    }];
    [alert addAction:buttonAdd];



    UIAlertAction *buttoncancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];
    [alert addAction:buttoncancel];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}}
```

Comment: do you reload tableview after delete?

Comment: Why do you update your `tableView` after one sec? Did you try to remove `dispatch_after` statement?

Comment: @SMi yes i have tried with reloading table as well

Comment: @Astoria: after struggling with standard code, i put the dispatch_after but WHY its not removing the cell/row. please see UPDATE1

Comment: do you update the database as well as the array

Comment: @AnuradhS: yes i deleted the row from database first than delete from the array containing model object. Earlier i tried with only deleteRowAtIndexPath but still remain issue, than i tried with fetching the array again from database and dispatch_after etc etc

Comment: I have the same problem. It's not great but to avoid the crash for now when I want to delete the last row I call reloadData() instead.

Comment: @MarieDm: Ok let me give one more try other wise i remove this module of deletion :P finger crossed.

Comment: please share your code for deleteGeofencingFormDatabase function..  [getObject deleteGeofencingFormDatabase:getObject.ah_routeid];

Comment: @iOS_devloper here it is: -(void)deleteGeofencingFormDatabase:(NSString *)ah_id
{
   NSString *deleteQuery =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM 'autohtch' WHERE ah_routeid = '%@'",ah_id];
   [[DBManager sharedDatabase] executeQuery:deleteQuery];
}

Comment: @iOS_devloper i think there isn't any problem in this, otherwise DBManager must have given error preparing statement. What you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out the solution that work for me. The problem was some where else and also modified the `commitEditingStyle:` to some extent.

```
routeTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-160)];
routeTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
routeTableView.dataSource = self;
routeTableView.delegate = self;
routeTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
routeTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
[self.view addSubview:routeTableView];
```

Firstly i move the above code in `viewDidLoad` - method, earlier it was written in `viewWillAppear`. Than I did changes in

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
    Geofencing *getObject = [routesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [routesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [deleteArray addObject:getObject];  //deleteArray collecting the object which will removed in viewDidDisappear
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [routeTableView reloadData];
    });
  }
 }
```

And finally

```
  - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (Geofencing *getObject in deleteArray) {
        [getObject deleteGeofencingFormDatabase:getObject.ah_routeid];
        [routeTableView reloadData];
    }
    [deleteArray removeAllObjects];
   });
}
```

Comment: Separated the data reloading part in table view from database deletion.